# RegEx OR operator not working in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to match two types of string such as below (parsing a header file)

```
txt='''\
STDMETHOD_(MyFunc)(
D2D1_SIZE_U size,
_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData,
) PURE;

STDMETHOD(MyFunc2)(
_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData2,
UINT32 pitch2, 
) PURE;\

STDMETHOD_(void, GetFactory)(
_Outptr_ ID2D1Factory **factory
) CONST PURE;
'''

matches = re.findall(r'(\bSTDMETHOD\b((.|\n|\r)*?)\bPURE\b)|(\bSTDMETHOD_\b((.|\n|\r)*?)\bPURE\b)',txt, flags=re.DOTALL | re.M)
print matches
```

In essence I want to combine these two RegExes:

```
r'(\bSTDMETHOD\b((.|\n|\r)*?)\bPURE\b)'
r'(\bSTDMETHOD_\b((.|\n|\r)*?)\bPURE\b)'
```

but the OR operator is not working. What bugs me is that if I paste these as

```
(\bSTDMETHOD\b((.|\n|\r)*?)\bPURE\b)|(\bSTDMETHOD_\b((.|\n|\r)*?)\bPURE\b)
```

in Notepad++ or VisualStudio it does find the matches propely, but in Python I get a bunch of empty strings, repeated strings, missing the key words `_STDMETHOD`, etc... here’s the output:

```
[stdout:][
    (
        '',
        '',
        '',
        'STDMETHOD_(MyFunc)(\nD2D1_SIZE_U size,\n_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData,\n) PURE',
        '(MyFunc)(\nD2D1_SIZE_U size,\n_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData,\n) ',
        ' '
    ),
    (
        'STDMETHOD(MyFunc2)(\n_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData2,\nUINT32 pitch2, \n) PURE', 
        '(MyFunc2)(\n_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData2,\nUINT32 pitch2, \n) ',
        ' ',
        '',
        '',
        ''
    ),
    (
        '',
        '',
        '',
        'STDMETHOD_(void, GetFactory)(\n_Outptr_ ID2D1Factory **factory\n) CONST PURE',
        '(void, GetFactory)(\n_Outptr_ ID2D1Factory **factory\n) CONST ',
        ' '
    )
]
```

If anyone can spot the bug, I greatly appreciate.

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the whole regex.

Comment: `|` **is** working, but you have multiple capturing groups within the expression...

Comment: the output I look for in this case is just the three functions nicely matched into a list, such as:

['STDMETHOD_(MyFunc)(D2D1_SIZE_U size, _In_opt_ CONST void *srcData, ) PURE', 'STDMETHOD(MyFunc2)(_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData2, UINT32 pitch2, ) PURE', 'STDMETHOD_(void, GetFactory)(_Outptr_ ID2D1Factory **factory) CONST PURE']

Comment: Then you either need to extract those sections from the tuples, or use non-capturing groups in the regex.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Or use `finditer`, which provides group zero, the whole match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `finditer` instead and ask each match object for the whole match:

```
for match in re.finditer(r'... your regex ...',txt, flags=re.DOTALL | re.M):
    print repr(match.group())
```

Output:

```
'STDMETHOD_(MyFunc)(\nD2D1_SIZE_U size,\n_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData,\n) PURE'
'STDMETHOD(MyFunc2)(\n_In_opt_ CONST void *srcData2,\nUINT32 pitch2, \n) PURE'
'STDMETHOD_(void, GetFactory)(\n_Outptr_ ID2D1Factory **factory\n) CONST PURE'
```

And check out [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall), which clearly describes the behaviour you observed.

Answer (score 0):

You can "merge" the regexes like this (since they differ in an underscore, I just added `_?` - an "optional underscore"):

```
(\bSTDMETHOD_?\b([\s\S]*?)\bPURE\b)
```

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/vF8iU6/2) and [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/QWTGD4).

You do not need any flags with `[\s\S]*?` since it matches any character, even a newline.